# 32-bit App with dynamic library crash on 64-bit device

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-architecture, arm64

I am facing the following scenario:

- 32 bit device + app armv7 + dynamic library armv7 arm64 =
  **work**
- 64 bit device + app armv7 + dynamic library armv7 arm64 =
  **doesn't work**

**doesn't work** - app crashes on load with the following error:

> dyld error message library not loaded reason no suitable image found

Any explanations?

Comment: armv7s ? - armv7 is really old

Comment: @DavidH it is not the point if is old or not. armv7 and armv7s are supported in arm64 devices. However, my question is, what happen if I add a load command to a dynamic library that is armv7... cause for me, it's crashing and I don't get why.

Comment: You only included the first line of the dyld error message. There should be more lines of output from dyld.

Comment: Please add full error log so that we can better understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**: 32 bit binaries loaded on 64 bit devices fail to do so since the 32 bit pagesize has been changed from 4096 bytes to 16384 bytes in iOS 9.

**Conclusion**: 32-bit apps with dynamic libraries cannot run on 64-bit devices.

**Solutions** (one of the two is enough):

- Add a new entry to Other linker flags in the dynamic library project:

  > -Wl,-segalign,4000
- Update app itself to support arm64 architecture