# NSCoding crash on encode only on 64bit devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, data-structures, nscoding

I have and app with 2 custom data structures, 1 named PaxData, the other ManifestData, basically ManifestData contains an array of PaxData.

Now this was all working fine, I then implemented my NSCoding, to have permanent storage. I Added it to my PaxData and my ManifestData file. Then I tried it on simulator with iPhone 4S, worked very well. Then tried with iPad Air... got a crash here :

```
aCoder.encodeObject(manifestPax, forKey: PropertyKey.manifestPaxKey)
```

My error : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Now my manifestPax is = to [PaxData]

after the crash I started digging, trying to find a solution, I eventually figured out that my app was always crashing on a 64 bit device, every time I run it on a Non-64 bits (4s-5-iPad 2) it works !

So now, I'm out of ideas... any help would be appreciated

Here's a little bit more of my ManifestData.swift file :

```
init?(date: NSDate, pilotName: String, acReg: String, manifestPax: [PaxData]) {

    self.date = date
    self.pilotName = pilotName
    self.acReg = acReg
    self.manifestPax = manifestPax

    super.init()

    if pilotName.isEmpty || acReg.isEmpty || manifestPax.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }

}

// MARK : NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(date, forKey: PropertyKey.dateKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(pilotName, forKey: PropertyKey.pilotNameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(acReg, forKey: PropertyKey.acRegKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(manifestPax, forKey: PropertyKey.manifestPaxKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let date = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.dateKey) as! NSDate
    let pilotName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.pilotNameKey) as! String
    let acReg = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.acRegKey) as! String
    let manifestPax = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.manifestPaxKey) as! [PaxData]

    self.init(date: date, pilotName: pilotName, acReg: acReg, manifestPax: manifestPax)
}
```

EDIT : Here's PaxData.swift :

```
init?(paxName: String, paxWeight: String, paxEmergencyName: String, paxEmergencyPhone: String, paxDestinationComments: String) {

    self.paxName = paxName
    self.paxWeight = paxWeight
    self.paxEmergencyName = paxEmergencyName
    self.paxEmergencyPhone = paxEmergencyPhone
    self.paxDestinationComments = paxDestinationComments

    super.init()

    if paxName.isEmpty || paxWeight.isEmpty || paxEmergencyName.isEmpty || paxEmergencyPhone.isEmpty || paxDestinationComments.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }

}
// MARK : NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(paxName, forKey: PropertyKey.paxNameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(paxWeight, forKey: PropertyKey.paxWeightKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(paxEmergencyPhone, forKey: PropertyKey.paxEmergencyPhoneKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(paxEmergencyName, forKey: PropertyKey.paxEmergencyNameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(paxDestinationComments, forKey: PropertyKey.paxDestinationCommentKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let paxName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.paxNameKey) as! String
    let paxWeight = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.paxWeightKey) as! String
    let paxEmergencyName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.paxEmergencyNameKey) as! String
    let paxEmergencyPhone = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.paxEmergencyPhoneKey) as! String
    let paxDestinationComments = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.paxDestinationCommentKey) as! String

    self.init(paxName: paxName, paxWeight: paxWeight, paxEmergencyName: paxEmergencyName, paxEmergencyPhone: paxEmergencyPhone, paxDestinationComments: paxDestinationComments)
}
```

Comment: Please try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707643/32-bit-app-with-dynamic-library-crash-on-64-bit-device

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `PaxData` (including its `encodeWithCoder(_:)` and `init(coder:)` method implementations?

Comment: Can't right now but I'll do as soon as I'm back at my computer thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to fix it, ran tests, and it works, it's actually very stupid. I went in Build setting, deleted the arm64 entry all together, ran the app on a simulator, stopped it, then re-added arm64 in the list of supported architectures.

[image]

It works now !